# How to maintain error log on in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using hockey app in xamarin forms application and it working fine when any exception generate it will send the report to hockey app.
But hockey app open a popup and its ask for-"Always Send","Send Now","Dont Send". so if the user select "dont send" then I will not aware of this exception.

So any other process to log the exception and save it to the device and when internet available it will automatically send to the server.

So What I am doing now-

```
Public Void MyFunction()
{
try
{
// my code
}
catch(Exception Ex)
{
// save the exception to local database
}
}
```

I save the exception to my local database and send it to my server when internet available.Is this a good Idea? or **suggest any other process to maintain this exception?**

Answer (score 3):

You should be using the [AppCenter SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/xamarin)

It is really simple, and at the moment provides all the functionalities you need.

You can track crashes, you can track exceptions and also events within your applications.

Just add the following Packages:

- Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics
- Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes

To your solution.  After this, create an account in [App Center Portal](http://appcenter.ms).

In your `App.xaml.cs` do the initialization:

```
AppCenter.Start("android={Your Android App secret here}" +
                  "uwp={Your UWP App secret here};" +
                  "ios={Your iOS App secret here}",
                  typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));
```

Then, to track your exceptions:

```
try
{
    //your code
} catch (Exception ex){
    Crashes.TrackError(ex);
}
```

Comment: Hockey app is totally free,but AppCentre is Paid

Comment: AppCenter is totally free.

Comment: @Vidhya AppCenter does have a free tier, which includes 4 hours builds / month/ organisation, and DO NOT INCLUDE the tests.

Answer (score 2):

You need to transfer to AppCenter.

In AppCenter, the pop up no longer appears which means they always send and HockeyApp is being retired in Nov 2019.

Comment: How to send the exception which are inside the catch block?

Comment: AppCenter has an analytics component which allows you to send any type of data up to the cloud that you may want to report on.  You can be online or offline when making that call, eventually it will go to the cloud when back online. This would mean using the framework instead of putting together your own custom DB related solution. I really do suggest you sign up to AppCenter and see what it has to offer.

Comment: Okey,Lets try App Center.Thanks